# Ionic css footer backgrond color and color of title

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic framework, and I need to have a  footer with background color red and with a text align in the center. The footer need to have a behaviour like a button; The footer is should be like a Button where in the center there is the text 'REGISTER':

I try this code:

IONIC HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  Some content!
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar  class="myColor">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">REGISTER</button>
  </div>
 </ion-footer-bar>
```

CSS:

```
.myColor{
   color:red
}

.button{
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
```

But, it doesn't work. i don't know;
Some of you have some good advice:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just set the whole footer as a clickable element like this:

```
<ion-footer-bar class="myColor" ng-click="myRegisterFunction()">
  REGISTER
</ion-footer-bar>
```

And then you can just use simple css:

```
.myColor {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
```

And in your controller you can call the function:

```
$scope.myRegisterFunction = function() {
  // do the registration stuff
}
```

Comment: You would probably want to use some !important tags for the color and other stuf to override the default of ionic

Comment: Well you could be right. There might be cases where you need to do that but if you setup your custom css correctly it will override the ionic defaults and there should be no problem :)

Answer (score -1):

`ion-footer-bar{ --background : blue; }`